# Force wrapping an inline-block with CSS, after 'n' elements?

Tags: html, css, line-breaks

I am trying to display a list of divs as a grid, using purely CSS, but I can't get it to behave properly. I had looked at `white-space: wrap`, but that is meant to be applied to the parent element, so that isn't useable. I also tried `clear`, but no luck either. Can anyone suggest an approach, that would work for any value of elements per row. The code below is intended to be three elements per line.

The reason I want this in CSS, is that code that this is part of is intended to allow the user to display the entries horizontally, vertically or as a grid (of n elements wide). The value of 'n', for the elements per row of the grid is based on a configurable value.

Intended display, for the grid view (where n=3):

```
Entry 1 | Entry 2 | Entry 3
--------+---------+--------
Entry 4 | Entry 5 | Entry 6
--------+---------+--------
Entry 7 | Entry 8 | Entry 9
```

```css
#results.grid {
  padding-top: 40px;
}
#results.grid .entry {
  display: inline-block;
}
#results.grid .entry:nth-child(3n+1) {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="results" class="results grid">

  <div class="entry">Entry 1</div>
  <div class="entry">Entry 2</div>
  <div class="entry">Entry 3</div>

  <div class="entry">Entry 4</div>
  <div class="entry">Entry 5</div>
  <div class="entry">Entry 6</div>

  <div class="entry">Entry 7</div>
  <div class="entry">Entry 8</div>
  <div class="entry">Entry 9</div>
</div>
```

As a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rn05gns1/

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/rn05gns1/1/ ?

Comment: "display a list of divs as a grid" is not clear enough. Please describe what you want

Comment: What determines how many elements are in a row?

Comment: In your example, `.entry` has a width of 200px, so each row of three (for example) needs at least 600px of width before wrapping.  How do you want to grid to behave for screens smaller than 600px width?

Comment: You should consider using Twitter Bootstrap (CSS library that provides responsive grid, among much more)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of inline block use *float*s:

```
#results.grid .entry {
   float: left;
}

#results.grid .entry:nth-child(3n+1){
   background-color: yellow;
   clear: left;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mode').change(function() {
    $('#results').removeClass();
    $('#results').addClass($(this).val());
  })
})
```

```css
#controls {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 4;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 4px
}
.entry {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin: 5px;
}
#results.horizontal {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-top: 40px;
}
#results.horizontal .entry {
  display: inline-block;
}
#results.vertical {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
#results.grid .entry.vertical {
  display: block;
}
#results.grid {
  padding-top: 40px;
}
#results.grid .entry {
  float: left;
}
#results.grid .entry:nth-child(3n+1) {
  clear: left;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results" class="results grid">

  <div class="entry">Entry 1</div>
  <div class="entry">Entry 2</div>
  <div class="entry">Entry 3</div>

  <div class="entry">Entry 4</div>
  <div class="entry">Entry 5</div>
  <div class="entry">Entry 6</div>

  <div class="entry">Entry 7</div>
  <div class="entry">Entry 8</div>
  <div class="entry">Entry 9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works, but then suffers wrapping when the space is reduced in width. I tried adding a ``overflow-x: scroll`` to avoid that, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Then you should write responsive css and from that width which wrapping begins remove `clear: left` property.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way that might work depending on your layout and other factors such as responsiveness.

Instead of inline-blocks, float your `.entry` elements to the left and apply `overflow: auto` to the parent container to contain the floated elements.  This prevents the floated `.entry` elements from interacting with other elements outside of `#results`.

The trick is to clear the floats every n-th element. To do this, define one or more classes like `.n3`, `.n4` and so on, and use the `nth-child` selected to apply the `clear:left` property to the first element of the row.

Any extra elements will simply give you a partially filled row.

As long at the page is wide enough, your rows will work as expected.  On smaller screens, the elements will wrap.  How you want to deal with this remains to be specified depending on your layout.

```css
.entry {
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin: 5px;
}
#results.grid {
  border: 1px dotted gray;
  overflow: auto;
}
#results.grid .entry {
  float: left;
}
#results.grid.n3 .entry:nth-child(3n+1) {
  background-color: yellow;
  clear: left;
}
#results.grid.n4 .entry:nth-child(4n+1) {
  background-color: green;
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<h3>Exampel 1: n=3</h3>
<div id="results" class="results grid n3">

  <div class="entry">Entry 1</div>
  <div class="entry">Entry 2</div>
  <div class="entry">Entry 3</div>

  <div class="entry">Entry 4</div>
  <div class="entry">Entry 5</div>
  <div class="entry">Entry 6</div>

  <div class="entry">Entry 7</div>
  <div class="entry">Entry 8</div>
  <div class="entry">Entry 9</div>
</div>

<h3>Exampel 2: n=4</h3>
<div id="results" class="results grid n4">

  <div class="entry">Entry 1</div>
  <div class="entry">Entry 2</div>
  <div class="entry">Entry 3</div>

  <div class="entry">Entry 4</div>
  <div class="entry">Entry 5</div>
  <div class="entry">Entry 6</div>

  <div class="entry">Entry 7</div>
  <div class="entry">Entry 8</div>
  <div class="entry">Entry 9</div>
</div>
```